# Proof that a continuous function on $[a,b)$ is bounded (epsilon-delta)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

Prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow b^-} f(x)$ exists, then $f$ is bounded, and for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \varepsilon$ for every two numbers $x, y \in [a, b)$ with $|x-y| < \delta$.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you then have a continuous function on $[a,b]$, which is therefore bounded?

Comment: Yes.  Or rather, you can "extend" f to a continuous function on [a, b].

Comment: I think the point of the OP is that he has been told to prove it using an epsilon-delta type proof. I.e. show that you get uniform continuity by showing the appropriate delta must exist.

Comment: $\lim \limits _{x \to b^-} f(x)$ exists *and is finite*. If the limit is infinite then your claim is not true.

Answer (score 2):

If that happens, we can extend $f$ continuously in the obvious manner to $[a,b]$. All your results now follow from the fact that the extension of $f$ is continuous in a compact set (Your results: namely, uniform continuity and boundedness).